# How to use different css files for admin front end and main site front end nuxt js

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am trying to use two different layouts for my project. Currently I am using css file in nuxt config file like this

```
css: [

   '~assets/css/main.css',
   '~assets/css/admin.css',
 ],
```

It works but the problem is if I add css files for admin layout all front end and admin css are used in both places. How can I use these css separately?
Thank you.

Comment: The docs tell you this: "*Nuxt.js lets you define the CSS files/modules/libraries you want to set globally (included in every page).*". So, you have 2 files you want to include in different pages? Don't add them to `nuxt.config.js`, add the specific file to each layout page.

Comment: Yes trying to do this too. Using local setting. 
head: {
   
    link: [
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'assets/css/main.css' }
    ]
  },

It gives errors  
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:9000/assets/css/main.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: ok I solved it. File has be publicly accessible